# INFORMATICA concatenation of ports

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Informatica 9.6 Developer Query
I am trying to concatenate 1 decimal (Input Port) and 1 integer (Variable Port) in one output port. But the result is not coming as expected.

```
PORT TYPE : NAME : VALUE
IP        : ACNT : 1567
VP        : SQ   : 10
OP        : ID   : ACNT || '.' || SQ
```

Expected Output Of ID: `1567.10`

Actual Output Of ID: `1567.1`

It is noted that zeros on the right side are truncated. Already tried to cast the numbers with `TO_CHAR()` function.

Comment: Try changing the data type of the ID field to string.

Comment: What is the type of the output port? It will never hold trailing zeros unless its a string, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression to ensure the length after the decimal point is always 2 by padding trailing 0's

`ACNT || '.' || RPAD(TO_CHAR(SQ), 2, '0')`